# How to implement bit error based on percentage in C?

Tags: c

I'm stuck at trying to simulate an Binary Symmetric Channel in C.

It should work like this: the user enters a number (for example 0.01 = 1%) which represents error rate. So, for instance, if i read 1001 from file every bit has a chance to change its value to 0/1 respectively depending on the entered percent.

Reading from file and writing into another is already working, but I just don't know how to make these percentage-based errors happen.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Far too broad. The bit-error rate alone is nonsense. There are other parameters you need. Even with that the question sounds like a request for code.

Comment: Well, since it's an assignment in class, we were given the BSC form which I explained and the way the user makes it work by using the command prompt: "program.exe source percentage destination". That's why I'm asking this, I'm stuck. Not asking for completed function, only for hints to make it work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For generating the percentage-based error, you could do something like this:

```
double rate = get_rate(); // userinput between 0.0 and 1.0 for 0% - 100%

do {
   double nr = drand48(); // Generates a number between 0.0 and 1.0
   if (nr < rate) {
       // Generate biterror here
   }
} while (some_more_bits_to_check);
```

Comment: `drand48` is non-standard. And that does not address other relevant parameters for bit-errors

Comment: This helped, only needed the logic you provided here with comparing the passed value with the generated. Thanks!